# What mode is this plainchant melody?

Tags: theory

[image]

https://gregobase.selapa.net/chant_img.php?id=7376

We start on sol and use sol-la-si/ti. We have two finalis: sancti ends on sol but amen ends on la. The recitation is la. Hypophrygian, I think, has recitation tone la with mi as finalis. But I cannot find the mode for this simple melody. In modern music we would say that Signum Crucis starts on Do abd end on do with amen ending on re which is not an ending tone.  
What mode is this?

Comment: Can you provide the URL for the page instead of the image? It's possible this was an input error in the database of melodies. I mean an error with the final neume. Maybe it is supposed to be a step lower?

Comment: There have been a few VsTC, but I think this question isn't a "basic analysis question", even though it's identification of a mode.

Comment: @Michael Curtis it's unlikely to be a mistake.  It is a common melodic formula in Gregorian chant.

Comment: @Phoog, I think if you explain that common melodic formula in an answer it would be helpful. I only have cursory knowledge of plainchant. I saw a few examples of a podatus ending _above_ the final, but most were a step below - meaning they stepped up to the final. I don't know the style well enough to explain.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I am working on an answer but it will probably take a few days to put together.  I'm a bit rusty on chant.  It would be better if someone with greater familiarity could answer.

Comment: I think there are Medieval theorists on this exchange, but maybe they are shy :-)

Comment: @MichaelCurtis part of the problem is that the 20th century chant materials from the catholic church use modern note names *(do* through *si)* rather than the Guidonian system.

Comment: I've been looking at guides like https://media.musicasacra.com/pdf/neumes.pdf and https://media.musicasacra.com/books/applied_course_chant_carroll.pdf, those combine neumes, solfege, and staff, but the topic isn't 'skimmable' it requires some deep knowledge

Comment: My quick review is Mixolydian mode, the final is on the 'ti' of 'sancti', and 'amen' is a code and not the proper ending, it's OK if it steps up to the second tone of the mode as what sound like a kind of half cadence to my modern ears. But, I don't offer that as a qualified answer, just a guess. Another forum member surely _knows_ better than me.

Answer (score 4):

Randomly happened upon this question in a search.  I don't know if anyone much cares about an answer here anymore.  But for the record, if what we're going for here is the Solesmes-type mode classification, the thing that really matters is the final note.  (Informational note: for those not as familiar with chant history, the Solesmes movement was/is a group of mostly monks who revived and revitalized the use of Gregorian chant in the Catholic Church beginning in the mid-late 1800s.  They standardized and produced modern editions of a lot of chant, in the process introducing various guidelines for singing that weren't always part of historical sources, including things like accent marks and frequently mode numbers listed for every chant.)

The Solesmes scholars would likely include the responsive Amen here as part of the chant, and thus classify it as **mode II, transposed**, based on the ending pitch of A and the fact that the ambitus doesn't go high enough to justify a mode I classification.

From another perspective, the Amen is just a generic congregational response and therefore perhaps not part of the Signum Crucis chant?  If you argue that, the Solesmes folks would stamp mode VIII on it (though, as I said, I don't think they'd separate the Amen).

The question seems to assume that things like recitation tones matter in mode classification.  That idea seems based on a concept that chants are composed with the mode classification system in mind, which generally wasn't the case.  The eight-mode system was imposed on a pre-existing body of orally transmitted chant, and there were many imperfect matches with chants that didn't really fit into the eight modes.  While there are definite characteristic patterns to chants in some modes (like melodic patterns or recitation notes), you'll sometimes find that same basic chant in another source that randomly has a lower final pitch, and thus Solesmes would just stamp a different mode number on it.  For example, you'll see a chant with mode III characteristics that's labeled as mode I just because that source happens to have a lower note tacked on for the ending.  Or sometimes the whole thing is basically transposed down a step, but retains a lot of the characteristics of the other mode.

Point being -- while modes have some characteristic melodic patterns, modern chant books tend to just put a number on based on the final and ambitus.  I don't mean to pick on Solesmes for this, as medieval books that started to classify *all* chants in the later medieval period generally did a similar thing.  (The earliest chant classification books from the 8th and 9th centuries seemingly did take melodic patterns into account, but that was for specific genres of chants, mostly antiphons, where modal classification wasn't about scale identification but about pairing one chant with the correct verse recitation formula for a psalm.  The psalm recitation formulas are mostly where we see "reciting tones" most clearly for each mode, but as the present chant under discussion isn't an antiphon or a psalm tone, all of that is pretty irrelevant.)

These very short chants, like the Signum Crucis or formulas for reciting a Bible reading or something, generally aren't even labeled with mode numbers in most modern editions, as they're not really "in a mode" in any meaningful sense.  There's not generally a lot of melodic material -- some of them literally are just one repeated pitch -- and in fact the Amen formula here is one of maybe three or four standard Amen responses that the choir/congregation tends to sing.  Sometimes these "Amen" chants are just listed on their own line in a manuscript source.  Are two or three notes covering only 1 or 2 pitches really "in a mode"?  (Also, a lot of these short formulas tend to end on things like A and B and C, and I think the Solesmes folks don't like writing "transposed" on too many chants, but that's my speculation.)

But if you adopt the idea that mode is generally defined by final note and ambitus (the later medieval conception of mode as applied to chant), it's pretty quick and easy to stamp a number on 99% of melodies.  Just keep in mind that anything that ends on A, B, or C needs to be viewed as something "transposed" from D, E, or F/G, to conform to the 8-mode system.

Comment: It's been a long time since I spent any time with the brothers if Solesmes, but I think you're right about the amen.

Comment: You can count one person glad you answered! If the "Amen" isn't included, the final is then `G`, right? But why would it be mode VIII not VII? There are no notes below the `G`.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - Because the Solesmes folks tend to slap mode VIII on pretty much any chant with a G final unless it has a high range.  I'm honestly not sure I can give you a better answer than that.  Well, I suppose having a recitation tone on A might be something they might bring out (yes, that's not the common *psalm* recitation tone for mode VIII, which is C, but it's more likely to occur as a repeated tone in mode VIII than VII). I can't say with 100% certainty what Solesmes would do, but my sense is they classify these simple chants with recitation on A or G ending on G as VIII usually.

Comment: Also, I might emphasize the first part of this, from Grove Online, "Inflection": "**The narrow ambitus of most Gregorian recitation tones prevents their being assigned to any of the church modes**, although they are characterized by an important modal feature, the positioning of the reciting note a tone or a semitone above its lower neighbour; the more ancient of the tones for collects and lessons seem to have favoured a reciting note on a or g, a tone above the inflections on g or f respectively."  While 7 or 8 could work given the limited range, my gut is that Solesmes would go with 8.